# DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: ID may not be NULL

Tags: sql, sqlite, perl, dbi

I try to insert a row using Perl in a table from an SQLite database.
The table has a column `ID` with the `AUTOINCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY` properties set.

From the `MY_TABLE` schema, this is all the information regarding the `ID` field:

```
ID [INT AUTO_INCREMENT] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

I don't want to configure the `ID` for each new row added, therefore I tried several ways to let the database to update it itself, but I get:

> DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: MY_TABLE.ID may not be NULL

```
use DBI;
my $db = DBI->connect("...");
my $sql = qq{
    insert into MY_TABLE (ID, col_b, col_c, col_d)
    values(?, ?, ?, ?)
}

my $st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute(undef, 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');
```

I also tried to skip the parameter completely from the query and from the parameters but same results. Putting `0` instead of `undef` inserts the actual value (which I don't want to, I want to be incremented automatically).

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please share the table structure ? You can just execute `.schema MY_TABLE;` from sqlite command line and update your question with the output.

Comment: @GMB I added the info for the `ID` field, unfortunately, can't share more.

Comment: Without the full definition of the table it is hard to tell exactly what is going wrong. Why can't you share more ? You can make anonymous the information that you don't want to share.

Comment: Also, `AUTO_INCREMENT` should be `AUTOINCREMENT` in sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As elsewhere mentioned, the correct spelling is AUTOINCREMENT, not AUTO_INCREMENT, but never mind about that, what you really need is to declare your ID field `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, *exactly* like that, `INT` isn't good enough, and you don't normally need the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword anyway (see under https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), and don't specify anything for ID in your `INSERT` statment.

Comment: Apparently the database which I received was wrongly configured with that `[INT AUTO_INCRMEENT]`. I didn't even considered I should check it first... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you should not pass an empty value to the column, but instead not pass the column itself.

Try :

```
use DBI;
my $db = DBI->connect("...");
my $sql = qq{
    insert into MY_TABLE (col_b, col_c, col_d)
    values(?, ?, ?)
}

my $st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute('val2', 'val3', 'val4');
```

Comment: @GarryWhite : there was an extra `?` that I forgot to remove. Please try again now.

Comment: `I also tried to skip the paramter completely from the querry and from the parameters but same results` ... I thought about it too, but it throws the same error

Answer (score 1):

```
ID [INT AUTO_INCREMENT] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

1. `AUTOINCREMENT` (Not `AUTO_INCREMEMENT`) only works with an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column (And usually shouldn't be used anyways as it doesn't do what the name implies; [details](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)).
2. Most sqlite tables have a primary key that's an signed 64 bit integer (The [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)). When inserting a new row, if a rowid value is absent or `NULL`, a new one is generated automatically (This is what people *think* `AUTOINCREMENT` does because they're used to how other databases work). An `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column acts an alias for the rowid and behaves the same way. Any other primary key is equivalent to a unique index on that column(s). The column affinity has to be `INTEGER` for a rowid alias. Nothing else, like `INT`. [More reading](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

So, basically, change your table definition to include

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

instead and you can leave it out of an `INSERT` or assign `NULL` to it and it'll work the way you want.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, as @varro already answered that was the mistake. I received the database and I wasn't considering checking whether it was correclty setup or not.